# Read file in java over more than one line

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

Hy,

I'm expiriencing logical troubles at reading a file, line for line. I know you can do this with `BufferedReader`, but sometimes I have "values" which are written in more lines, which would be important.

Sample of the file im reading:

```
   <#FIELD NAME = DESC> Some text that goes

        over multiple lines

        which is needed</#FIELD>

    <#FIELD NAME = TEMP> some values are just a single line</#FIELD>
```

I need to parse the Field Name, which would be TEMP or DESC like above, and then extract the value between those brackets `<#FIELD NAME =DESC>important values </#FIELD>`. But I'm not really sure how to "recognize" that an entry has a multiple line value or a single value line and then save it to a variable, when using BufferedReader.

I would really appreciate any hint or example to direct me into the right direction !

Because reading it line for line, did not help me progress... I will not post the whole code as I think there is a more easier way to read it and you will get an idea of what I've done so far by this little snippet.

```
if (line.contains("<#FIELD NAME = AUTOR>"))
{
    String autor = line.substring(line.indexOf(">") + 1, line.indexOf("</#"));
    metaData.setAutor(autor.trim());
}
else if (line.contains("<#FIELD NAME = DOKUMENTNR>"))
{
    String dokumentnr = line.substring(line.indexOf(">") + 1, line.indexOf("</#"));
    metaData.setDoukumentnr(dokumentnr.trim());
    ...
```

Comment: looks like xml.  Have you considered options in the xml space (sax's xmlreader for eg)?

Comment: No this may look like an xml but unfortunately its not !

Comment: @Adam: reading it with BufferedReader as described.

Comment: Hi, If the String is starting with "<",Store this String in a variable. add a "/" at the first position to this variable .Read the values until you reach this variable.

check for the string "name" in the tags and read the value.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the </#FIELD> of the previous entry is not on the same line as the <#FIELD ...> of the next? Then reading all lines until you hit </#FIELD> should do, shouldn't it?

Comment: I would use the same approach SAX parses use which is to not read by line but parse by character and break up the input in a series of events like `start of field NNN` `attribute name + value` `text block` `end of field`  While the format is not exactly the same, I believe the same approach is approriate.

Comment: @SrinivasB I don't think that this is a clean solution in any way...

Comment: @mkl yes but I need to read more than those 2 values, could you provide me some pseudo code, I think you are poiting in the right direction.

Comment: If the format is as simple as you show, read everything into a String (s), then s.split("<#FIELD"), then do more parsing. but this should help with the multi-line issue.

Comment: @auselen but then I don't know which values is for which key.

Comment: why? you would still get the "NAME = DESC" at the beginning of the strings in the array generated by the split.

Comment: Could you provide me some pseudo code or an example, because your approach sounds really good ! And if it helps me you should post it as an answer so I can accept it ;-)

Comment: Please explain how you data is **NOT** XML. Absence of XML header is not considered an obstacle. I would say that if your data resembles XML than use XML parser - it will simplify your job and avoid most errors. For example your code would break if any of your fields contained sub-fields...

Comment: Simple as that, it is NOT a valid XML Structure. Maybe my snippet makes you think it is, but it is definately NOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
public string ReadField(BufferedReader reader) 
{
    string line = reader.readLine();
    while (line.indexOf("</#FIELD>") == -1)
    {
        line += reader.readLine(); // This does not preserve line breaks
    }

    return line;
}
```

In the original code, something like

```
string line = ReadField(myReader); // This reads up to the next field

if(line.contains("<#FIELD NAME = AUTOR>")){
   String autor = line.substring(line.indexOf(">")+1,line.indexOf("</#"));
   metaData.setAutor(autor.trim());
} else if(line.contains("<#FIELD NAME = DOKUMENTNR>")) {
   String dokumentnr = line.substring(line.indexOf(">")+1,line.indexOf("</#"));
   metaData.setDoukumentnr(dokumentnr.trim());
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you ! That points me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
while((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
    if(isDescOrTemp(line)){
        if(line.endsWith("</#FIELD>"){
           //one line field
        } else
        while(!line.endsWith("</#FIELD>"){
            //read more lines
            line=reader.readLine();
            //store line somewhere
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No thats nor really what I need.

Comment: Previous example was thinking shortcut, but for you more elaborate example

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, if you don't have an hierarchical data (like a tree), it means you have a list, so you are looking for a way to split it. Normally you should write a clean parser but if that's not the case you can try to hack your way.

```
String s = "<#FIELD NAME = DESC> Some text that goes\nover multiple lines\nwhich is needed</#FIELD>\n<#FIELD NAME = TEMP> some values are just a single line</#FIELD>";
String[] fs = s.split("<#FIELD NAME = ");
for (String f : fs) {
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

produces

```
DESC> Some text that goes
over multiple lines
which is needed</#FIELD>

TEMP> some values are just a single line</#FIELD>
```

After this you need to clean up your result strings by removing the `</#FIELD>` at the end and reading the key at the beginning.

Comment: The problem with that is that in the file there are no /n. I really only would get the line of '<#FIELD NAME = DESC> Some text that goes' which would not contain the whole value !

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a pseudocode like below:

```
While(!EOF)
{
    string line = readLine();
    while( !EOF && ! line.contains("</#FIELD>"))
    {
        line += readLine();
    }
    // Here you get a line with matching `begin` and `end`

    // ... do operations as needed

    // reset line
    line = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<#FIELD.+</#FIELD>", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    for(;;) {
        String field = s.findWithinHorizon(p, 0);
        if (field == null) {
            break;
        }
        // here you got a full #FIELD element, parse it
        System.out.println(field);
    }
```